# Gravitational compression / compression in general

Tags: mass

How exactly does gravitational compression, or compression in general, increase temperature? It seems counter-intuitive seen as temperature usually increases from the solid to the gas phase.

Comment: See the animation at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Charles_and_Gay-Lussac%27s_Law_animated.gif - this should give an intutive idea.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar: The GIF you linked is for ideal gas temperature-volume relationships, which behaves in the opposite manner as what the OP is asking about, which is gravitational temperature-volume relationships. For a gas, when you increase the temperature, the volume increases, whereas for objects under gravitation, when the volume increases the temperature decreases.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus The OP has said "compression in general".

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar: True, but the GIF you linked does the opposite of what the OP is talking about.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Right - I understand. Thanks. BTW, your answer is amazing. +1!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gravitational self-energy of any arbitrarily-shaped object with density function $\rho(\mathbf{r})$ and corresponding gravitational potential $V(\mathbf{r})$ is
$$E=\frac{1}{2}\left\langle V,\rho\right\rangle=\frac{1}{2}\left\langle \nabla^{-2}\rho,\rho\right\rangle=\iiint\nabla^{-2}\rho(\mathbf{r})\rho(\mathbf{r})d\mathbf{r}.$$
Under a scale-parameter compression by a factor of $\lambda$, notice that $\rho$ transforms as $\rho(\mathbf{r})\rightarrow\lambda^3\rho(\mathbf{\lambda r})$ and $V$ transforms as $\nabla^{-2}\rho(\mathbf{r})\rightarrow\lambda\nabla^{-2}\rho(\lambda\mathbf{r})$, which implies that the gravitational self-energy transforms as 
$$E\rightarrow \iiint\lambda^4\nabla^{-2}\rho(\mathbf{\lambda r})\rho(\lambda\mathbf{r})d\mathbf{r}=\iiint\lambda\nabla^{-2}\rho(\mathbf{ r})\rho(\mathbf{r})d\mathbf{r}=\lambda E.$$
As a result, when an object is compressed by a factor of 2, its self-energy also increases by a factor of 2.

For astronomically-sized objects, this can be enough energy to heat objects to enormous temperatures when the underlying material is sufficiently compressible, releasing huge amounts of heat in the process.

The physical intuition is that when an object is compressible under its own gravity, the object collapses under its own weight; this means that work is being done on the object by itself. The mechanical work energy has to go somewhere, and so it becomes heat.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So the object does work on itself and in turn increases its internal energy. (change in internal energy = heat added + work done) No heat is added but work is done, so the change is positive. It is an adiabatic process then?